# i cannot make sticky header work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to make a theme for wordpress and i am trying to make a sticky header but the sticky header just doesn't seem to work, maybe it is the javascript. Can you help me?

this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var nav = $('.topmenu');
        var top = $(".topmenu").height();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > top ) {
                nav.addClass("sticky");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Well do you have a rule  for `sticky` in your CSS?

Comment: Wordpress uses jQuery noconflict mode, which could be your problem. Try changing your first line to `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

Answer (score 2):

Create a fixed class, the following class fixes a div to the bottom of the page. You won't need javascript unless you intend to turn the fixed class on and off and then the code you already have will do that through Jquery addClass/removeClass:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following for your header.
SCript File:

```
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
$('.topmenu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.topmenu').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left', leftOrgElement + 'px').css('top', 0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
}
```

This works for me

Comment: You're assuming too much about OPs html, not to mention a simple CSS class could make a header sticky. This is completely overhead

Comment: yes i thought they wanted to stick it after scroll. My mistake.

Comment: and if they want to scroll they dont have to edit the original "css". just add the name of the "css" atribute to the file and it will stick on scroll.